# How to find the exact group of digits?

Tags: regex

So i have a text 
`Server Version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) PHP/5.4.16` 
and want to  find 2.4.6 and 5.4.16
There may be more (2.4 or 5.4.12.16) and etc. But i dont want any of .12 or 9999.1111 to find

My attempt so far looks like this:

```
/([\d{1,2}\.]{2,})/g
```

You can also see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/hV0hN0/1

It does not work.

Comment: Why don;t you put the reg exp in your post?

Comment: Try [`\b\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/hV0hN0/3). It matches 1 to 2 digits only after a word boundary, and then 1+ sequences of a `.` followed with 1+ amount of digits. Maybe allowing 1 to 3 digits will be OK - `\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})+`

Comment: Look for the slash `/(?:\/)....`

Comment: Or `(?:Apache|PHP)\/([\d.]+)`

Comment: What are the criteria for a number being too large? Is it 2 digits throughout as your attempt suggests? I.e. `2.3.123` isn't allowed?

Comment: Actually you can search for a leading slash and then find numbers and dots up until the next \s: https://regex101.com/r/hV0hN0/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(?<!\.)\b(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})+)\b(?!=\.)
```

It checks for a word boundary `\b` **not** preceded by a `.`. Then digits, followed by **at least** one `.` and 1-2 digits. Finally confirm that a `.` follows.

[Your regex modified](https://regex101.com/r/hV0hN0/6).

Comment: IT also takes 9999.1111.

Comment: @MichałM Yes, and why shouldn't it? Have I missed som requirement?

Comment: " But i dont want any of .12 or 9999.1111 to find" o.O

Comment: @MichałM Oops. Misread that as `.12`, `9999.` and `1111` thinking - it cant start or end with a `.`, nor be an integer.

Comment: Edited to allow a maximum of two digits in the minor numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe
`(?<!\d)\d{1,2}([\.]\d{1,2})+`
always from your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\/\K((\d{1,2}\.)+)\d{1,2}
```

Comment: The regex flavor is not specified, we can't be sure it is PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

What you think about:

```
^\d(\.\d{1,2})+$
```

This is a short and clean version.
Matches:
2.4.6 and 5.4.12.16 but won't match .12 and 9999.1111